# Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, dependencies

im a beginner and  idk how to solve this error, i've tried  resolving by changing deploy settings but cant fix this compilation error ,i cant understand what these errors want me to do except these too much syntax errors is there anything im not aware of?

here's the log deploy

```
5:02:48 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
5:02:49 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
5:02:49 PM: Failed to generate package.json data, continuing with build
5:02:49 PM: Starting build script
5:02:49 PM: Installing dependencies
5:02:49 PM: Python version set to 2.7
5:02:50 PM: v16.19.0 is already installed.
5:02:50 PM: Now using node v16.19.0 (npm v8.19.3)
5:02:50 PM: Enabling Node.js Corepack
5:02:50 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
5:02:50 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
5:02:50 PM: Attempting Ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
5:02:51 PM: Using Ruby version 2.7.2
5:02:51 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
5:02:51 PM: Started restoring cached corepack dependencies
5:02:51 PM: Finished restoring cached corepack dependencies
5:02:51 PM: No npm workspaces detected
5:02:51 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
5:02:51 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
5:02:51 PM: Bypassing sha validation. Running pre & post install scripts
5:02:51 PM: Installing npm packages using npm version 8.19.3
5:03:10 PM: added 438 packages, and audited 439 packages in 19s
5:03:10 PM: 100 packages are looking for funding
5:03:10 PM:   run `npm fund` for details
5:03:10 PM: 1 high severity vulnerability
5:03:10 PM: To address all issues, run:
5:03:10 PM:   npm audit fix
5:03:10 PM: Run `npm audit` for details.
5:03:10 PM: npm packages installed
5:03:11 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
5:03:11 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
5:03:11 PM: go version go1.19.5 linux/amd64
5:03:11 PM: Detected 1 framework(s)
5:03:11 PM: "next" at version "12.3.0"
5:03:11 PM: Installing missing commands
5:03:11 PM: Verify run directory
5:03:11 PM: Section completed: initializing
5:03:12 PM: ​
5:03:12 PM:   Netlify Build                                                 
5:03:12 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:03:12 PM: ​
5:03:12 PM: ❯ Version
5:03:12 PM:   @netlify/build 29.5.4
5:03:12 PM: ​
5:03:12 PM: ❯ Flags
5:03:12 PM:   baseRelDir: true
5:03:12 PM:   buildId: 63e0ec4c48ae074d1e9ce655
5:03:12 PM:   deployId: 63e0ec4c48ae074d1e9ce657
5:03:12 PM: ​
5:03:12 PM: ❯ Current directory
5:03:12 PM:   /opt/build/repo
5:03:12 PM: ​
5:03:12 PM: ❯ Config file
5:03:12 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
5:03:12 PM: ​
5:03:12 PM: ❯ Context
5:03:12 PM:   production
5:03:12 PM: ​
5:03:12 PM: ❯ Installing plugins
5:03:12 PM:    - @netlify/plugin-nextjs@4.30.3
5:03:19 PM: ​
5:03:19 PM: ❯ Using Next.js Runtime - v4.30.3
5:03:20 PM: ​
5:03:20 PM:   1. @netlify/plugin-nextjs (onPreBuild event)                  
5:03:20 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:03:20 PM: ​
5:03:20 PM: No Next.js cache to restore.
5:03:20 PM: Netlify configuration property "build.environment.NEXT_PRIVATE_TARGET" value changed.
5:03:20 PM: ​
5:03:20 PM: (@netlify/plugin-nextjs onPreBuild completed in 14ms)
5:03:20 PM: ​
5:03:20 PM:   2. Build command from Netlify app                             
5:03:20 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:03:20 PM: ​
5:03:20 PM: $ CI='' npm run build
5:03:21 PM: > material-kit-react@2.1.1 build
5:03:21 PM: > next build
5:03:21 PM: warn  - No build cache found. Please configure build caching for faster rebuilds. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-cache
5:03:21 PM: info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
5:03:24 PM: 
5:03:24 PM: Failed to compile.
5:03:24 PM: ./src/components/account/account-profile-details.js
5:03:24 PM: 51:16  Warning: Prop `props` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: 60:20  Warning: Prop `xs` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: 73:20  Warning: Prop `xs` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: 84:24  Warning: Prop `md` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: 95:24  Warning: Prop `md` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: 106:24  Warning: Prop `md` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: 117:24  Warning: Prop `md` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: 130:46  Warning: Prop `value` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: 146:35  Warning: Prop `variant` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: ./src/components/account/account-profile.js
5:03:24 PM: 39:41  Warning: Prop `gutterBottom` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: 42:43  Warning: Prop `variant` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: 45:43  Warning: Prop `variant` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: 52:31  Warning: Prop `fullWidth` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: ./src/components/account-popover.js
5:03:24 PM: 39:44  Warning: Prop `variant` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: ./src/components/auth-guard.js
5:03:24 PM: 42:5  Warning: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'isAuthenticated' and 'router'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
5:03:24 PM: ./src/components/layout.js
5:03:24 PM: 39:54  Warning: Prop `open` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: ./src/components/nav-item.js
5:03:24 PM: 22:29  Warning: Prop `passHref` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: ./src/components/navbar.js
5:03:24 PM: 75:39  Warning: Prop `onClick` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: 106:33  Warning: Prop `handleClose` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-line
5:03:24 PM: ./src/components/settings/settings-password.js
5:03:24 PM: 129:49  Warning: Prop `title` must be placed on a new line  react/jsx-max-props-per-
5:03:24 PM: ./src/pages/Update/index.js
5:03:24 PM: 38:33  Error: React Hook "useState" is called in function "index" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use".  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
5:03:24 PM: 39:35  Error: React Hook "useState" is called in function "index" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use".  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
5:03:24 PM: 40:33  Error: React Hook "useState" is called in function "index" that is neither a 

5:03:24 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
5:03:24 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:03:24 PM: ​
5:03:24 PM:   Error message
5:03:24 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: CI='' npm run build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
5:03:24 PM: ​
5:03:24 PM:   Error location
5:03:24 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
5:03:24 PM:   CI='' npm run build
5:03:24 PM: ​
5:03:24 PM:   Resolved config
5:03:24 PM:   build:
5:03:24 PM:     command: CI='' npm run build
5:03:24 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
5:03:24 PM:     environment:
5:03:24 PM:       - NEXT_PRIVATE_TARGET
5:03:24 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/build
5:03:24 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
5:03:24 PM:   plugins:
5:03:24 PM:     - inputs: {}
5:03:24 PM:       origin: ui
5:03:24 PM:       package: '@netlify/plugin-nextjs'
5:03:24 PM: Caching artifacts
5:03:24 PM: Started saving node modules
5:03:24 PM: Finished saving node modules
5:03:24 PM: Started saving build plugins
5:03:24 PM: Finished saving build plugins
5:03:24 PM: Started saving corepack cache
5:03:24 PM: Finished saving corepack cache
5:03:24 PM: Started saving pip cache
5:03:24 PM: Finished saving pip cache
5:03:24 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
5:03:24 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
5:03:24 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
5:03:24 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
5:03:24 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
5:03:24 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
5:03:24 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
5:03:24 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
5:03:24 PM: Started saving go dependencies
5:03:24 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
5:03:25 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
5:03:25 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
5:03:25 PM: Finished processing build request in 37.866s
```

and this is my deploy setting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyYld.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just an issue in the code. if you try to run `yarn build` or `npm run build`. locally it will also fail on the same component.

Since Eslint will firstly check if the code written is correct and uses the correct best practices before it lets the build start. EsLint seemed to spot a component that failed to compile and yelled at you for not fixing it before building.

This it what it said:

```
Failed to compile. ./src/components/account/account-profile-details.js
```

It basically says to the developer, hey check out this file `account-profile-details.js` it probably has some issues...

Since you didn't share the content of the file with the error, I cant help you any further than this. But my best guess is to look at the file above and try to figure out why it's not working.

Good luck!

Comment: locally while running " npm run dev " it is not generating any compilation  error rather its running smoothly , its just creating issue while deployment .                                                                secondly it's creating warnings and errors in manyyyyy files  not only in one or 2 files , i tried to paste whole deploy log but there's a  number limit here for lines.                                                   also see the stupid errors  and warnings  like" this word must be placed in a new line"

Comment: Yes indeed, running "npm run dev" won't fail since this is just starting the development server not the production build. try running "npm run build"